# Compiling C++ code makes the system hang

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, g++

When I try to compile this file by issuing the command, "g++ qr.cpp -o qr" The system hangs. I haven't seen this kind of an error anywhere else.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

bool win[1000000001];
bool know[1000000001];

int sixes[] = {6, 36, 216, 1296, 7776, 46656, 279936, 1679616, 10077696, 60466176, 362797056};

bool check(int n){
   cout << n << endl;
   if(!know[n]){
      bool b = check(n-1);
      for(int i=0; i<11; i++){
         if(n > sixes[i]){
            b = b & check(n-sixes[i]);
         }
      }
      win[n] = !b;
   }
   return win[n];
}

int main(){
   win[1] = know[1] = true;
   for(int j=0; j<11; j++){
      win[sixes[j]] = know[sixes[j]] = true;
   }
   int n = 1; 
   cin >> n;
   int i = 0;
   while(n != 0){
      i++;
      win[n] = check(n);
      cout << i << (win[n]?"-Heckle":"-Jeckle");
      cin >> n;
      if(n!=0) cout << endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

My compiler version information is given below.

```
yasith@vostro:~/Dropbox/Shared$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,go --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3)
```

Comment: Uh, those are some *REALLY* big arrays. Are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: do you really need that much STATIC memory?!

Comment: I've noticed that when the compiler compiles a chunk of code it allocates the static memory of the program for testing purposes before creating the executable.

Comment: FYI, I tried compiling your source anyway.  The compilation passed, but when I tried to run executable, it said, "Killed"... probably because I only assigned 1GB of RAM to my virtual machine.  XD  (Slackware64 13.37 running on vmware btw)

Comment: advice: `malloc` is your friend!

Comment: allocate only when you need to

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do you realize how big these are?

```
bool win[1000000001];
bool know[1000000001];
```

Those are at least 1GB each!!! You're gonna want to allocate them dynamically...

Comment: that's a decent sized BSS section haha

Answer (score 5):

It compiles fine with g++ 4.6.1 on my Debian system, which only has 1GB of memory.

I tried looking at the memory used by the various passes of the compiler and the linker when changing the size of the arrays, and the memory use didn't change much, indicating the compiler wasn't trying to allocate any data-structures proportional to the array size.

*However*, I have the new GNU linker "gold" installed.

I then tried it again, using the older ("BFD-based") GNU linker, which is still the default on many systems, for the link step—and *then* my system started thrashing like crazy (I had to kill the linker process)!

So it seems that the new gold linker is smarter about big arrays than the older linker.

On Debian, gold can be installed as the system linker by just installing the "binutils-gold" package.  [I don't know if Ubuntu has the same package, but as Ubuntu is based on Debian, it seems likely.]

Comment: Yes, I noticed that too. If you use "g++ -S" then it works fine. I will try installing the binutils-gold.

Answer (score 4):

You're allocating 2GB of static space. Try changing the size and recompiling?

```
bool win[1000000001];
bool know[1000000001];
```

Answer (score 3):

The code, while a bit insane, should not hang the compiler. If it's a true hang (i.e. more than a few minutes), report it as a GCC bug.

Comment: Actually -- it appears the bug is a ld/libbfd bug, based on snogglethorpe's work.