# why g++ compiler use so much memory?

Tags: c++

I wrote a simplest c++ program in my ubuntu server:

test.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int a[100*100*100*100*10];
int main() {
    unsigned int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100*100*100*100*10; i++) {
        if (i % 10000000 == 0) cout << i << endl; 
        a[i] = i;
        count += i; 
    }
    cout << count << endl;
}
```

and my g++ compiler is:

```
root@ubuntu:~# g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
```

the memory of my server is 64GB.
when I run `g++ test.cpp`, it need about 1 minutes to compile this c++ file. and the peak usage of g++ progress is 5GB memory....

why?

by the way, when i run this program, it need about 1minutes to finish.
I think may be there is something wrong with my memory.
is it because the memory is too large？

Comment: As an aside, might I suggest `const int BufferSize = 100*100*100*100*10;` instead of using the same magic number twice

Comment: I suspect stackoverflow.com is not the right place for this question to be asked, however… if you change the size of your constant you will likely see different performance from the compiler. You haven't mentioned what compiler flags you're using but if there's any optimization being performed, this constant could be a huge problem as a loop sentinel (while the compiler decides if it should unroll the loop).

Comment: Compilation took just 2 seconds on a VM with 2GB of RAM.  Of course I can't run the program there, but if you actually need 1 minute to compile this program I'd say there is something very horribly wrong. Can you run a quick hd perftest (`hdparm -t /dev/yourhd`) to see whether it's memory or disk io related?  And check dmesg, maybe your disk is dying on you.

Comment: `int a[100*100*100*100*10]` Are you on drugs?

Comment: `root@ubuntu` looks very scary.

Comment: @fvu: Not really; that's a lot of operations and a lot of console output.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, that's a lot of operations, but it's just ~100 lines of output.

Comment: @Shahbaz: What can I say? Consoles are slow. (Yes, okay, I was a tens unit out :P)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first issue about memory usage of the compiler is a bug in gcc/g++. This question was raised before but I can't seem to find it now. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7831275/912144) hinting at the same issue, but I clearly recall a more direct mention of this bug.

Anyway, in short, the problem is the following. First, let's say your array is initialized:

```
int a[100*100*100*100*10] = {10, 20};
```

This means that now the whole array should be actually written in the executable (so should also first reside in g++'s memory).  This is slow because `a` is really large (4GB). Now if the array wasn't initialized, as is with your case, it should go to `.bss` section and the whole array is allocated/initialized just when you run it. This means that it doesn't need to be written to the file.

This also means that g++ can skip having the whole array in memory. This is where the bug comes in. g++ *does* keep that array in memory and only later decides not to write it. This bug is later fixed as you can see in reports in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19838857/912144).

---

The second issue with execution taking long is natural. You are doing something one billion times. Doing something one billion times takes time!

A good rule of thumb is "a loop of 10 million lightweight calculations takes in order of a second". So you can imagine 100 times 10 million operations would take about 100 seconds (i.e. in order of a minute).

Comment: The third issue is that is normally you resort to dynamic memory allocations for anything that is biggish (and 3.7 GB is definitely big).

Comment: @MatteoItalia, that _is_ what you would normally do yes. But that's not related to why the complitaion and the execution take such a long time. Otherwise there are sure a lot of issues with the code itself. For example `count` is unsigned while being added with signed numbers besides being small enough to very easily overflow when summing one billion numbers.

Comment: Of course, but I wanted to point it out, since to me this is the most obvious problem with that code; the very fact that such a bug slipped in in `g++` comes from the fact that you are not supposed to have such big global arrays anyway.

Comment: Even with the initialization you give, the array could go in .bss.  It's only when there is an initialization other than 0 that it must go into .data.

Comment: Not that it has to, of course.  I've used more than one compiler which put anything with initialization in `.data`, even if the initialization was to `0`.  But if the initialization is all 0's, it's quite valid to put the object in `.bss` as well, which makes for a smaller executable.  (Usually, the difference in size will be negligible, but in this case...)

Comment: @JamesKanze, of course. That's why you had written "the array _could_ go in .bss" ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have no problem with it - it works fine.

I would have guessed it's because it tries to figure out whether to unroll the loop or not, but since you don't use any optimization flags…

Side note: You should not compile could as root.

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu8' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu8)
```